# Convert a 2010 13" macbook pro screen into a monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

***This was posted before but the answered were not very specific, slightly newer model than mine and a few years old.***

I was considering converting the screen of the old 2010 13" macbook pro into a monitor, the laptop works, but connectors are worn and prone to disconnection for slight movements, need an ssd to be of any real basic us and its just not got the processing power to do much that Id like to.

As similar macbook pros in better conditions are selling for about £50+ online, I thought it'd make a great case for a raspberry pi build I have in mind.

I need a driver board for the display, (and for the backlight I believe from other poats), but I've never tried doing this before.

I would very much welcome any info or links to possible suitable driver boards.

I will either use the screen for the main raspberry pi 4b monitor or make it into a all purpose spare screen.

Comment: Where was it posted before?

Comment: In this forum, I can't recall the name of the poster, a couple of years ago. But the links in it were dead. That is unless I have missed a more recent post

Comment: So you should be able to find it, help us not repeat things.

Comment: It’s [unlikely any Mac portable would be easily reusable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42608/5472) without expensive parts and skill. [Purpose built monitors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254829/5472) are typically more cost effective.

Comment: Luke Miami did some work on Macs . Check his video to see if you can find some ideas (for example video connector to use build in screens)